# Understanding IServiceManager::getInterfaceDescriptor() is not static

Tags: android, c++, android-source

When I read `aosp`sources, `IServiceManager.cpp IServiceManager.h`, I find the code. I know it's from macro

```
 DECLARE_META_INTERFACE (ServiceManager, "android.os.IServiceManager")IMPLEMENT_META_INTERFACE(ServiceManager, "android.os.IServiceManager"); 

        #define DECLARE_META_INTERFACE(INTERFACE)                           \
            static const android::String16 descriptor;                      \
            static android::sp<I##INTERFACE> asInterface(                   \
                    const android::sp<android::IBinder>& obj);              \
            virtual const android::String16& getInterfaceDescriptor() const;\
            I##INTERFACE();                                                 \
            virtual ~I##INTERFACE();
```

After translating a piece of code, it's like this

```
class IServiceManager : public IInterface
{
public:
    DECLARE_META_INTERFACE(ServiceManager);
.......
```

==>

```
class IServiceManager : public IInterface
{
public:
.......
    const android::String16& getInterfaceDescriptor() const;  //macro be translated
.......
```

`asInterface` is `static` and OK. `getInterfaceDescriptor` is not `static` method of  class but `virtual const`. Why the method `getInterfaceDescriptor` can be invoked by `IServiceManager` class directly ?

```
        virtual sp<IBinder> checkService( const String16& name) const
        {
            Parcel data, reply;
            data.writeInterfaceToken(IServiceManager::getInterfaceDescriptor());
            data.writeString16(name);
            remote()->transact(CHECK_SERVICE_TRANSACTION, data, &reply);
            return reply.readStrongBinder();
        }
```

Where I am wrong? If you know, please tell me. Thanks.

I write a test code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class AA {
    public:
        virtual void bb() {
            cout<<"sdfsdf";
        }
    };

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    AA::bb();
}
```

Error happens.

```
Untitled 4.cpp:13:6: error: call to non-static member function without an object argument
        AA::bb();
        ~~~~^~
1 error generated.
```

Comment: What's you real question? Is it that how (static) method of an interface can be called without derived class?

Comment: Yes, the method is instance method of IServiceManager. It's  called by  IServiceManager::getInterfaceDescriptor(). Why?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, stupid for me, just because I am not familiar with C++ programming. `IServiceManager::getInterfaceDescriptor()` be called in its derived class. So it's way of call super class instance method. I messed it with Java.

Test code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class AA {
    public:
        virtual void aa() {
            cout<<"sdfsdf";
        }
};

class BB : public AA {
    public:
        void bb(){
            AA::aa();
        }

};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    BB bObject;
    bObject.bb();
}
```

It runs well.